# What's the best way of truncating Date to 15 minutes interval

Tags: java

I'm looking to code a function that would truncate a timestamp received to the nearest previous 15 minutes interval. 
I.e. 01:16:58 -> 01:15:00, 01:02:32 - >01:00:00, 01:30:00 ->01:30:00 etc.

Any idea of a nice simple way of coding it?

We're on Java 8

Thanks

Update: Pls note that the truncation is required, not the rounding. This is how the question is different from the other one that has been mentioned by a number or readers.  So, this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: what have you tried so far? a minute is an int, how would you round an int to the previous 15min?

Comment: How many seconds are 15 minutes? If you would know that - could it help? Do you know the modulo operator? Btw.: Finding the nearest, previous value isn't called rounding, it's called truncation. So 13:59:59 gets 13:45:00, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the truncation is required, not rounding. This is how this question is different from the one mentioned earlier.

Comment: this is called rounding down... or flooring, in some other circles. There is literally nothing different with "truncating", one of the answers in the duplicate target addresses exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    final int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.set (Calendar.MINUTE, minutes - (minutes % 15));
    cal.set (Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set (Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    System.out.println (new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```